# Unable to map fields when exporting to CSV

Tags: reports, export, field-mapping

We are unable to map fields when exporting to CSV. Using Primary Field export gets us the standard csv, but when option to select fields for mapping is checked, seems to go into a loop (see attached screenshot). Cannot use a previously saved field mapping either.
We are running Civicrm 5.32.2 with Joomla 3.9.23 on PhP 7.4 server. Wasn't a problem before last Joomla/Civi updates.
thanks,
Kate

`[image: export screenshot]

Comment: Have you checked the Civi logs at ConfigAndLog? Or your webserver error logs? I'm not a Joomla user, but that's where I'd start.

Answer (score 0):

This is working on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm

It will help if you can add your CMS version, CiviCRM version etc to your question. This could be something interfering with the display of the 'add field' feature

[image]

If you know how to use your browser 'inspect' you may be able to identify an error in your Console

Comment: Config was included in original post:  We are running Civicrm 5.32.2 with Joomla 3.9.23 on PhP 7.4 server.

Comment: sorry. yes i see it was. fail of my speed reading

Comment: Any solutions out there? Still happening with Civi 5.3.1, Joomla 3.9.26.